# Problems with my list (Weird Malloc Error Continued)

Tags: c, list, shell, malloc

I decided to specify my quesiton because I was able to sniff out some of what was specifically going on. Apparently, it has something to do with the list, but I am not so sure how to fix it. More speficially, I am looking for a way to try and rewrite a certain segment of the list, but it gives me an error which you would know about had you read my previous post.

Here's my code for the List Handling:

```
typedef struct list_t
{
    pid_t pid;
    int jid;
    char *runstat;
    char *cmdline;
    struct list_t *next;
} list_t;

list_t *jobs_list = NULL;

void add_element(list_t **list, pid_t pid, int jid, char *runstat, char *cmdline)
{
    list_t *e;

    if (*list == NULL)  // New empty list.
    {
        *list = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t));
        (*list)->pid = pid;
        (*list)->jid = jid;
        (*list)->runstat = strndup(runstat, MAXCHARS);
        (*list)->cmdline = strndup(cmdline, MAXCHARS);
        (*list)->next = NULL;
    }
    else  // List with at least one element.
    {
        // Loop through elements, so that e is left
        // pointing to the last one in the list.
        for (e = *list; e->next != NULL; e = e->next)
            ; // (Do nothing.)

        e->next = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t));
        e = e->next;
        e->pid = pid;
        e->jid = jid;
        e->runstat = strndup(runstat, MAXCHARS);
        e->cmdline = strndup(cmdline, MAXCHARS);
        e->next = NULL;
    }
}

void fg_list_handler(list_t ** list, pid_t pid, int jid) {

}

void change_running_status(list_t **list, pid_t pid, char *runstat) {
  //THe code I wrote with changing statuses in the list for programs.

  list_t *e;

  e = *list;

  if (e->next == NULL) {
    strncpy(e->runstat, runstat, MAXCHARS);
  } else {
    for (e; e != NULL; e->next) {
      if (pid == e->pid) {
        strncpy(e->runstat, runstat, MAXCHARS);
        break;
        }
  
    }
  }

 

}
```

Do you have any idea of how to fix it so I can change a certain value of a list without getting a Heap Corruption error for no understandable reason?

Comment: Try running your code with either a debugger or a tool like Address Sanitizer to get more details on the accesses that are happening. Depending on the compiler you're using, this may be as simple as setting one or two compiler options.

Comment: I am running on Replit.com, and I don't think they have a debugger. The compile options I use are as follows

Comment: gcc shell.c csapp.c -lpthread -o shell

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strndup), `strndup` returns _a null-terminated byte string, which contains copies of **at most size bytes**_ which I take to mean it can alloc less than`MAXCHARS`. If you want to use `strcpy` later, `malloc(MAXCHARS)` instead.

Comment: You may want to consider using your own environment that you control for this, in the future. Nothing stands out at a quick glance, and I'd need to be back at a computer to have a chance of testing it with ASan/a debugger.

Comment: There is also https://www.onlinegdb.com/ .You can't write any somewhat complex code without debugging it. Coming with each issue to SO is not a solution.

Comment: All the code is over in the othe question if you want to test it. Be careful though.

Comment: Note that `strncpy()` will not write a null terminator if you hit the length limit. Always write one into the last element.

Comment: How am I supposed to write a Null Terminator? I've never done that before in my life.

Comment: @bf3019 My suggestion is that you test it with these tools, in order to get hands-on experience. If you're learning to program, it's vital that you get to know **all** of the basic tools that you might use, including your own compiler, debugger, and common debugging tools like runtime sanitizers. Either it spits out some findings and you figure out the answer, or it spits out some findings that you can add here so people answering don't need to guess as to what is going on.

Comment: Following `strncpy(e->runstat, runstat, MAXCHARS);` you can do `e->runstat[MAXCHARS-1] = 0;`

Comment: @nanofarad Dude, I'm almost through with it and I just want someone to figure out what's up with this thing. It's been just one problem to iron out after another and just me having to go baack and fix up something one step of the way after another. Usually, in highschool, I could get a code to run easy peasy with no errors whatsoever. It's like I'm losing my touch.

Comment: I share some of your frustration in my experience. When I started writing more complicated programs, I found that I was a lot more frustrated with debugging until my skills in reading and debugging programs caught up to my skills in writing them. Set up the environment, try some more suitable tools to help debug, and see if they work. You can't always dump your program on someone else and ask them to debug it. If you aren't willing to even try those tools, and aren't willing to try something with a learning curve, you can't really call yourself a "master" of the field.

Comment: And yes, being "almost done" with a program, and then having to patch up one bug, then another, then discover that something else needs to be changed, is a part of life.

Comment: I need this though. I have a deadline to reach and it's too soon. I can't do this in 5 hours.

Comment: Then you've hopefully learned a valuable lesson here -- you need to build time in for debugging and changes when planning out a project or task. With that said, it also takes nowhere near five hours to install an environment with a debugger. You can even use "onlinegdb" as suggested above. It's your program, you know its design and your intentions better than any of us do, so you are the best equipped to debug it.

Comment: Another possible lesson is to thoroughly test each section as you write it, as you can usually only dash off a small program and expect it to work flawlessly. The alternative is a pile of code riddled with errors that is harder, in the long run, to debug and get working, and uncertainty whether it still contains bugs.

Comment: *"Learnning curves don't exist to me.... I avoid them at all costs as I am a master anyway."* - learning curves exist for *everyone*, including us. If you think I can do what I do *regardless* of the quarter-century of engineering experience under my belt, think again. Divine intervention notwithstanding, mastery comes from practice, repetition, failure, and eventually, hopefully, success. If you think we were born into this with talent already-installed, you couldn't be more wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Easy peasy ... ;-)*

In `add_element`, do *not* use `strndup`--it doesn't help your situation (use `strdup` instead).

It does *not* guarantee that the result is `MAXCHARS` in length.

In `change_running_status`, using `strncpy` can corrupt the heap if the length of the `runstat` argument is greater than what was created by `strdup` (nee `strndup`) in `add_element`.

---

For example ...

If you do:

```
add_element(&mylist,pid,jid,"foo","bar");
```

But, then, later do:

```
change_running_status(&mylist,"hello world");
```

This will overflow the allocated space for `e->runstat` and corrupt the heap.

---

Note that in the `for` loop the iteration clause is: `e->next`. This has *no* effect. You want: `e = e->next`.

Here's the corrected code:

```
void
change(list_t *e,const char *runstat)
{
    char *str;

    // safety -- dup the string first to prevent [possible] use after free
    str = strdup(runstat);

    // free the old string
    free(e->runstat);

    // add in the new string
    e->runstat = str;
}

void
change_running_status(list_t **list,pid_t pid,char *runstat)
{
    // THe code I wrote with changing statuses in the list for programs.

    list_t *e;

    e = *list;

    if (e->next == NULL)
        change(e,runstat);
    else {
        for (;  e != NULL;  e = e->next) {
            if (pid == e->pid) {
                change(e,runstat);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My god! Finally, someone who actually helped me! Thanks! You're a hero! I think I am losing my touch at programming though. I will get checked out as to why I'm losing my talent.

Comment: You're "losing your talent" because you're under stress. This happens when you encounter the first time that you're going a little beyond your current ability. Welcome to the club ... You've never had to be patient [with yourself] because it's always been "easy". That's where _persistence_ pays off. (e.g.) Add an extra semicolon in the wrong place in some code can trigger a four week debug session [until one finds the error].